# Modulating Ratio in FM8

Tags: sound-design, synthesis

It seems that there should be a way to modulate the ratio of an operator via an LFO in FM8. Why is this not a possibility? What are the alternatives?

Comment: What do you mean"why is this not a possibility?" Are you asking about the design decisions made by the developers of the software?

Comment: @RoryAlsop yes from a design decision. I feel like automating the ratio and offset would be a core feature that we would want to have

Comment: ...then you'd be better off asking the developers, rather than random, unaffiliated strangers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can.

If you use the Pitch Envelope, you can set it to loop (or use one of the "Loop" presets). Turn off Pitch Envelope modulation for all the ops except the one you want to modulate. Set depth using the Amplitude knob on the pitch page.